# How containers are linked to each other in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

To build a web-server, i'm trying to understand how containers are **attached** to each other, and i really need some quick answers. 
So, if we take this `docker-compose.yml` file as an exemple:

```
version: '2'

services:

    # APP
    nginx:
        build: docker/nginx
        volumes_from:
            - php
        links:
            - php
        depends_on:
            - php

    php:
        build: docker/php
        volumes:
            - ${SYMFONY_APP_PATH}:/symfony
        links:
            - mysql
            - faye
            - rabbitmq
            - elasticsearch

    client:
        image: node:8.9.4
        volumes_from:
            - php
        working_dir: /symfony
        user: 1000:1000
        command: "npm run dev"
        ports:
          - "${LIVERELOAD_PORT}:35729"
        environment:
          LIVERELOAD_PORT: ${LIVERELOAD_PORT}

    mysql:
        build: docker/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - ${SYMFONY_APP_PATH}:/symfony
            - "mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3.4-management
        volumes:
          - "rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq"

        volumes:
          - "elasticsearch5:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
          - ${SYMFONY_APP_PATH}:/symfony
volumes:
    mysql: ~
    elasticsearch5: ~
    rabbitmq: ~
```

What is the difference `between` `volumes_from`, `links`, and `depends_on` ? 

If the idea is to attach each container with the other why we don't use only `links`. what is the difference between `volumes_from`, `links`, and `depends_on`.

Why in my example `ngnix` depend/linked to `php` container? why not the opposite?

At the file footer, there's a volume configuration 
`volumes:
 mysql: ~ elasticsearch5: ~ rabbitmq: ~` but I think we already defined as the volume of each container, so what's is the main reason of that config?

And why not we dont use only one web container that use php, ngnix, and mysqld why we seperate them?

Comment: this is website where people come for help with programming bugs, not to answer newbies questions "why". https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok think you i understand i gonna delete the question, any way can you come to chat i really need some explination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between volumes_from, links, and depends_on?

Both `links` and `depends_on` provide a way for a container to communicate with each other.

`links` is a legacy feature and will be deprecated in the future, so avoid using `links` whenever possible.

`volumes_from` is used for other purpose, and it has nothing to do with `links` and `depends_on`.

> Why in my example ngnix depend/linked to php container? why not the opposite?

`depends_on` defines order of services starting. In your example, you're using Nginx as a proxy server to the PHP service. So you might want the PHP service to start before Nginx.

> And why not we dont use only one web container that use php, ngnix, and mysqld why we seperate them?

One of Docker's best practices is to keep each container simple enough to do only one job. Much like Unix's "do one thing and do it well" philosophy.

Single responsibility principle is a good thing, embrace it.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration,
so here if we have a  php contanier, a ngnix contanier, where the web app will live ?

Comment: Live in the PHP container.

Comment: Why not on the nginx ?

Comment: What is the architecture of your system? Try to figure out each component's responsibility first.

Comment: can you explain more, it's just a php application

Comment: And how the nginix will call the php contanier, normally they should n be seperated